# Get handles of process forms c#

Tags: c#, process, window-handles

I have a process which opens a form and a tray icon on startup. I want to discover from a c# application what is the handle of the form and tray icon of the exe process above, and what are the handles of all child windows of this exe.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a perfect duplicate, but in the same spirit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019066/get-all-window-handles-for-a-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the window handle it is easiest to use `System.Diagnostics.Process` and the `MainWindowHandle` property. You don't state how you want to identify the other process but the `Process` class has lots of options for that.

Regarding the notification area icon, there is no API for what you are asking. You'd need to either hook the `Shell_NotifyIcon` API or modify the other process to cooperate.