# C# - Check if Handle is active

Tags: c#, handle, taskmanager

There is a Task Manager alternative called "ProcessHacker".
With that you can check if a Handle is active and running.
[image]

I would like to add something like that into my C# program, searching for a specific Handle and if Handle exist do smth...

Is there a reference, nuget or smth I can use?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: This? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019066/get-all-window-handles-for-a-process/22440420

Comment: Call `Process.GetProcesses()` and iterate over all the processes?

Comment: Process.GetProcesses().Where(....).

Comment: Also if you already have a specific handle, you can just open the process directly by using `Process.GetProcessById(handle)`. NOTE: Your application will likely require admin rights before it can modify some processes.

Answer (score 2):

```
var process = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.Handle.ToInt32() == 0x3b4);
```

As Matthew Watson noted:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessById(0x3b4);
```

would directly get that process with handle. Former's result is an IEnumerable.

Comment: Or `var process = Process.GetProcessById(0x3b4);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson, exactly. I wanted to show how would that be with other properties too. Where result would be an IEnumerable BTW.

Comment: thanks a lot that works :)